# Lightweight cache system for java?

Tags: java, caching

I've been looking for a lightweight caching system for java, I've been exploring a few different options; I'm wondering what people think would be the easiest one to implement and what would be the most lightweight.

These are what I've been exploring:

1. Guava cache
2. EHCache
3. Using redis and making my own system

I'm also open to other ideas, currently, I'm using a hashmap and just getting the values from there; I'd like something a little bit more feature rich. I don't have any **needs** per say, but there are certainly some things that would be handy such as a TTL and max sizes, etc. etc.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) is an in-memory cache for Java 8, with a Guava like api. The [benchmarks](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Benchmarks) are favorable.

Answer (score 2):

"Lightweight" is a little broad. Within [cache2k](http://cache2k.org) I try to address it in different ways:

- Low overhead (See [benchmarks](http://cache2k.org/benchmarks.html))
- Low memory consumption
- Basic compatibility with Java 6, to be usable within Android
- More useful stuff, like JMX support, is optional and in additional jars

Anyway your question(s) should be more specific. It does not comply with the general question guidelines. The question is to broad and you are asking for a product.

Answer (score 0):

Guava cache is great if you're only looking for simple, non-distributed solution. I would also recommend [Infinispan](http://infinispan.org/tutorials/embedded/index.html) - it's extremely easy to setup for single host application and not that hard for distributed one.

Comment: great but limited, Caffeine has ability to set custom expiry policies and cache2k can do variable expiration and other nifty things with expiry